# Users with Read access don't see pictures stored in Extended text field in document Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

we have document library at SP-2010 foundation. One column is used for storing pictures, type of the column is Extended text. There is group for Read-only access and 3 named users for Full access. Every user can see items in the library, but only user with Full access to the library can see pictures. All other users see in item only black icon with white cross instead of pictures.
The library has versioning active, but there is allowed to see draft items to any user with Read access, there is no request for approval.
How to allow Read only users to see full context including the pictures?

**User with full access see this:**

[image]

**User with Read access see this:**

[image]